# How can I check in the database for true/false value in admin, and redirect accordingly? (web application)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, web-applications

I have a basic login system on Java Eclipse IDE with tomcat server and mysql database. My code below shows a login validation. The program searches the mysql database for employee_id and password and if found in database, it will redirect to a page "Options.html". If the employee_id and password are not found, it will print "Employee ID or Password incorrect, please try again". Basically, what I want, is the following:

There is a column in my table called Admin, which is by the datatype TINYINT. This is basically a boolean, so either 1 for admin or 0 if not admin. I want the validation process to check if the user is an admin or not. If the user is an admin, I want it to go to Options.html (which is the current default). If the user is not an admin, I want it to go to another html page. Thanks in advance, below are my files.

Login.java (servlet)

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String employee_id = request.getParameter("employee_id");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(Validate.checkUser(employee_id, password)) { 
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Options.html");
            rs.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
           out.println("Employee ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again.");
           RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
           rs.include(request, response);
        }
    }  


        }
```

Validate.java (class)

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Validate
{
    public static boolean checkUser(String employee_id, String password)
    {
        boolean st = false;
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ?");
            ps.setString(1, employee_id);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
             st = rs.next();

         }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
             return st;                 
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Simply add a `AND Admin=1` in your query.

Comment: @Cyval But if Admin=0 I want it to go to another html file. How would that be done?

Comment: @Cyval Ah i see, I'm not sure how to implement that in my code though.

Comment: Apologies, I haven't experienced using Java with MySQL, I only know how the process goes.

Comment: @Cyval No problem, but thanks anyways for your contribution! I'll wait and see if someone else can help with implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have two separate functions for your validate class.

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Validate
{
   public static boolean userIsAdmin(String employee_id, String password)
   {
    boolean st = false;
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ? AND admin=1");
        ps.setString(1, employee_id);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
         st = rs.next();

     }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
         return st;                 
  }   

  public static boolean userIsNotAdmin(String employee_id, String password)
   {
    boolean st = false;
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ? AND admin=0");
        ps.setString(1, employee_id);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
         st = rs.next();

     }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
         return st;                 
  }  
}
```

Then add this in your main:

```
if(Validate.userIsAdmin(employee_id, password)) { 
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Options.html");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
 else if(Validate.userIsNotAdmin(employee_id, password))
    {
       RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("other.url");
       rs.include(request, response);
    }
 else
    {
       out.println("Employee ID or Password is incorrect. Please try again.");
       RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
       rs.include(request, response);
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah! Thanks very much for that! :)

Comment: That's some dirty code from a non-java programmer, but I guess you get the concept. :) Happy coding this 2016!